# Unity - I can't seem to link the Animator to my script

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, animator

sorry if this is a really simple question, but I really can't figure it out. I'm making a game in which I'm starting off with a tutorial on movement and combat etc, but when I try to animate my tutorials using the same line of code that worked for my player movement script, it won't work. By "it won't work", I mean that whenever I save my script (called "Next_Script") and go back into Unity, I don't have the option to drag in my Animator component. Again, the answer is probably extremely simple, but I can't figure it out. Thanks. The line of code I'm using is

```
public Animator animator;
```

It worked perfectly on another script, so I don't know why it won't here. Here's a photo of my inspector in Unity.

[image: Picture (It wouldn't let me post it on its own)]

For some reason it keeps changing my unity2d tag to unity 3d. It is 2d

Answer (score 0):

Your script reference is broken so it isn't even recognized by Unity ...

This happens sometimes if you delete or rename or move the script outside of Unity after it was already attached to a `GameObject`.

**First as the warning says make sure there are no compiler errors.**

Then first of all drag in your script into the field `Script` of the missing component. This tells Unity again which script to use for the component it isn't recognizing anymore.

After that you should again see your `Animator` field where you can drag in your Animator as usual.

---

So from the comments I know you **have** compiler errors for your code

```c#
public class Next_Script : MonoBehaviour 
{   
    public Animator animator;      
    public float Yay = 0f; 

     // Update is called once per frame    
    void Update()     
    {                  
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        Yay + 1f;
        animator.SetFloat("Next", Yay);      
    }      
}
```

Here are multiple problems:

1. You do **not** want to use `Thread.Sleep` in Unity! This freezes your entire GUI mainthread!

   For calling something repeatedly delayed among a lot other options you can use e.g. [`InvokeRepeating`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.InvokeRepeating.html), a simple timer or a Coroutine (see examples below)
2. And then `Yay + 1f;` makes no sense ... you either want to assign this value to something or use `Yay++;` or `Yay+=1`

So your code should look like e.g.

```c#
public class Next_Script : MonoBehaviour 
{   
    public Animator animator;      
    public float Yay = 0f; 

    void Start()
    {
        InvokeRepeating(nameof(Increase), 5f, 5f);
    }

    void Increase()     
    {                  
        Yay += 1f;
        animator.SetFloat("Next", Yay);      
    }      
}
```

Or using a simple timer in `Update`

```c#
public class Next_Script : MonoBehaviour 
{   
    public Animator animator;      
    public float Yay = 0f; 

    private float timer;

    void Update()     
    {  
        timer += Time.deltaTime;

        if(timer < 5f) return;

        timer = 0;

        Yay += 1f;
        animator.SetFloat("Next", Yay);      
    }      
}
```

Or using a [`Coroutine`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html)

```c#
public class Next_Script : MonoBehaviour 
{   
    public Animator animator;      
    public float Yay = 0f; 

    private float timer;

    IEnumerator Start()
    {
        while (true)   
        {  
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(5f);

            Yay += 1f;
            animator.SetFloat("Next", Yay);      
        }   
    }   
}
```

Comment: Yeah, there is a compiler error, but I didn't think the two problems were related. I've tried solving it through Stack Overflow, but the answers given weren't all too clear to me since I'm a beginner

Comment: Well as said you have to fix all compiler errors first! Otherwise your script might not be compiled. What is the error you get?

Comment: Assets\Next_Script.cs(19,9): error CS0201: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Comment: here's my code, sorry for the bad formatting: ```public class Next_Script : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Animator animator;

    public float Yay = 0f;
    

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        Yay + 1f;
        animator.SetFloat("Next", Yay);


    }

   
}```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it. The reason I used ```Thread.Sleep``` was so that there would be a delay to allow the player time to read, but I can find some other way of doing that if what you've said doesn't work

Comment: Fixed it already ;) please see the bottom of the answer .. there are the three most commonly used techniques for delaying stuff in Unity

Comment: Thanks, I only saw this now. What you said gave me an error, but I can't get at my laptop for another 8 hours ish so I'll post it here when I get at it. Thanks anyway though, since I asked one question and you've answered a different one that needed answerinh

Comment: Thank you so much, the program works fine now. Also thanks for helping with my other problem that I thought was unrelated. I mean, there is a small bug in the code but at least it works, again, thanks